# Combinar dos códigos de la misma función

Tags: php, wordpress-plugin

Tengo instalado un plugin para Wordpress llamado wp datepicker que consiste en un calendario para seleccionar fechas. Se trata de la web de un restaurante y el calendario se usa para las reservas. El restaurante cierra los lunes, así que implementé un código que deshabilita todos los lunes para que no se puedan reservar. El código es este:

function (date) { var day = date.getDay(); return [(day != 1)]; }

Ahora me piden que deshabilite además una semana determinada porque van a cerrar por vacaciones. Tengo el código para ello y funciona bien:

function (date) {
var array = ["2022-06-27","2022-06-28","2022-06-29","2022-06-30","2022-07-01","2022-07-02","2022-07-03"];
var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", date);
return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]; }

Mi problema es que ambos códigos funcionan, pero solo si uso uno de ellos. Si pongo los dos tal y como están, solo funciona uno.
Necesito saber la manera de combinarlos en uno solo para funcionen ambos a la vez. He probado varias maneras y no lo consigo.
¿Alguien puede ayudarme?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Mi problema es que no sé apenas nada de programación. Solo soy un diseñador gráfico metido en un lío del que no sé cómo salir.

Comment: Prueba cambiando el retorno de la segunda función por: `return array.indexOf(string) == -1 && date.getDay() != 1; `